# Sitecore 9.1 Installation errors

Tags: sitecore9

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot remove item C:\solr-7.6.0\server\solr\mhp_xdb\data\index\write.lock: Access to
the path 'write.lock' is denied.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDSJU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stopping the Java process, this will cause the write.lock file to be removed and solr will be able to create new cores

Comment: could you please explain how to stop the Java process?

Comment: Open up Windows Task Manager, go to the Details tab, find the Java.exe process and click End task. You'll then be able to add new cores.

Answer (score 0):

remove the core from solr , (first unload it from solr instance and then remove the core folder ) , and then try to run the script again